# Making core data App iCloud capable

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I have a core data OSX app and want to enable iCloud, to have the same data on any device of the iCloud user.

I read this article.
[Core Data iCloud Syncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388308/core-data-icloud-syncing) , but the method explained there seems to be deprecated (NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey).

What´s the recommended way today to implement the requirement.
As I want the app to be offline capable, I would like to use core data as local store, is that still recommended?

I see these options:

- implement as recommended in the article and use the deprecated things.
- use core data as local store and do the iCloud sync via cloud kit. 
  That seems to be not so simple. I did not find any article/tutorial for this way. Does it make sense? Are there any examples?

What advantages / disadvantages do you see in these options.
Is there another better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [seam3](https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3)